# BFS and DFS goal check

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Correct me if I'm wrong, as I understand BFS does a goal check every time a node is expanded. When a node is expanded, the algorithm checks all the children of the node before it expands a new node.

Does DFS do this too? When a node is expanded does the algorithm check all the children of the node before it expands a new node?

[image]
Graph. Starting node: S. Goal nodes: G1, G2, G3

With a BFS the expanded nodes will be S -> A -> G1 (because of goal check after expanding A).

Will this be the solution for DFS aswell?

Comment: *"With a BFS the expanded nodes will be S -> A -> G1"*: why would you expand G1?

Comment: A BFS would check all the neighbouring nodes first, meaning `S -> A -> G1` isn't correct. Unless you are doing something special there to look ahead, but I don't think that's what you mean with goal check. `S -> A -> G1` is rather the standard DFS behavior.

Comment: First, when expanding S, the frontier would be A, B and D. Then A will be expanded and the new frontier will be B, D, G1. Because BFS does an early goal check, the algorithm immediatly expands G1, and returns the solution S -> A -> G1.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, `BFS` uses Queue data structure and `DFS` uses Stack data structure. The processes are similar in both cases, but how you order the nodes is key. I hope this will help you.

And for your question, the answer is:

if the last node added was `A` then the route taken would be `S -> A -> G1` since DFS uses Stack

If any other nodes have been pushed at last, then DFS will process all its child nodes, and once it's finished, it'll come to the second last node and just go on.